# Test whether globbing is enabled

Tags: bash, wildcards

I know that i can enable/disable globbing with `set +f` and `set -f`.

But how can i test whether it is currently enabled?

I could create a file with a unique name and test if a file exists with a pattern that should match it. However, I hope there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you do `set -f`, or otherwise disable globbing:, [`$-`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0024_002d) will contain `f`:

```
$ echo $-
himBHs
$ set -f
$ echo $-
fhimBHs
$ bash -fc 'echo $-'
fhBc
```

So:

```
[[ $- = *f* ]]
```

Or:

```
case $- in
 *f*)  ... ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 7):

In `bash` at least, I don't know if this is shell-specific, you can use `test -o <optname>`.  The option name corresponding to `-f` is `noglob` so you can do something like this:

```
$ set -f
$ test -o noglob; echo $?
$ set +f
$ test -o noglob; echo $?
```

or, in a script,

```
if [ -o noglob ]; then
    echo globbing disabled
else
    echo globbing enabled
fi
```

Comment: `test -o` is non-standard, so it would be shell-specific.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't check but I was afraid of that.

Comment: Well, the question _is_ tagged with [tag:bash], so...

Comment: @Kusalananda That `-o` option to `test` comes from ksh, like the corresponding option to `set` and to the shell itself. `set -o` was in ksh86 already, but not `test -o` (which appeared in ksh88). I suppose, like the unary `-a`, it was not specified by POSIX because it conflicts with the binary `-o`. zsh supports `[[ -o ]]` (there's no conflict with binary -o there), but not `[ -o ]`.

Answer (score 5):

The variable `$-` has the current flags in it.

So you can do

```
case "$-" in
   (*'f'*) echo "file globbing is disabled" ;;
   (*)     echo "file globbing is enabled" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Why the single quote around  `'f'` in your `case` switch ?

Comment: The '(' is permitted by POSIX  but not needed. In 1990, people believed it is needed for `$(cmd)` but this was wrong. Shells that require it are broken anyway, so there is no need to use it in examples.

Comment: @Cbhihe Habit. Quote everything that is fixed to make it clear that it is fixed.

Comment: The extra optional `(` helps editors as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways.

- The most portable test is expanding `$-`

  ```
  set -f; [ -z "${-##*f*}" ] && echo noglob set
  ```
- In bash and a few shells:

  ```
  [ -o noglob ] && echo noglob
  ```
- A test for a few shells is:

  ```
  set -o | grep noglob
  ```
- The one meant for bash only is:

  ```
  $ shopt -op noglob
  shopt -o noglob               # +o if globbing is active.
  ```
- And, if you need a silent test:

  ```
  if shopt -oq noglob; then echo noglob set; fi
  ```
- You can also test by what globbing does (quite portable):

  ```
  set -- .*; if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then echo glob active; fi
  ```